# Late Binding Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, option-strict

Trying to set my labels text to = the value of a specific row & columns value. I prefer to use Option Strict On but its disallowing the late binding. Ideas?

```
Private Sub BuildText(ByVal dtData As DataTable)
    Try
        lblVendor.Text = CType(CStr(dtData.Rows(0)("Vendor").value), String)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Late binding is not really the issue there.  The issue is that you're trying to use a member that doesn't exist.  The `Item` property of a `DataRow` is type `Object`. Does the `Object` class have a `value` member? No, it doesn't.  All you needed was to cast the `Object` reference as type `String`, i.e. `CStr(dtData.Rows(0)("Vendor"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value you can use `Field(Of T)`

```
lblVendor.Text = dtData.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("Vendor")
```

[DataRowExtensions.Field(Of T) Method (DataRow, String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1))

To use this you'll need to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions